# PHP redirect/load another page

Tags: php, api

I know how to redirect/load with this code'

```
header('Location: http://www.someURL.com');
```

But what about using with strings?

```
$edit_invoice = $invoice->invoice->links->edit;
header( 'Location: '.$edit_invoice.' ) ;
```

I'm using Freshbooks API library in case you're wondering..

Comment: Remove that last single quote and it should work

Comment: Well, if you get errors, or you don't get redirectered at all, its time to check what does the string contain. So `print_R($edit_invoice)`.

Comment: Wrong markup: `header( 'Location: '.$edit_invoice.' ) ;` -> `header( 'Location: '.$edit_invoice ) ;`

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra apostrophe.
    header( 'Location: '.$edit_invoice ) ;

Answer (score 0):

The way you have the string version set up right now won't work, because you're starting a new string at the end of calling the `header()` function.

```
header('Location: ' . $edit_invoice);
```

Should work, as long as `$edit_invoice` is a valid link.